# Sync data Adapter from Service Android every second

Tags: android, service, android-recyclerview

I'm new in Android development. 
I have a problem with a sync beetween adapter data model and custom service.

Trying to explain better:

I have an ArrayList of Custom class in my service, because I have to count seconds (even if the app is closed) and print in a RecyclerView. Such as :

```
ArrayList<Custom> lists;
```

And the class Custom

```
Public class Custom{
   private seconds = 0;
   private EventBus eventBus;
   ...
   public int getSeconds(){
      return seconds;
   }
   public void addSecond(){
      seconds++;
   }
   public void eventBus(){
      if(eventBus == null){
         eventBus = new EventBus();
      }
      App.bus.post(eventBus);
   }

}
```

So I have a Adapter that print in RecyclerView the seconds of my Class such as:

```
public class ListCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListCustomAdapter .ViewHolder> {
 ...
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Custom custom = customs.get(position);
    holder.seconds_test.setText(String.valueOf(custom.getSecond()));
 }
}
```

Now In my service I have a function that addSecond to my customClass:

```
private addSeconds(){
   Timer chrono = new Timer();
   chrono.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
        public void run() {
           custom.addSecond();
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 custom.eventBus();
              }
            });

        }

   }, 0, 1000);
}
```

So, I would like have a adapter with a list of custom Class that can print a seconds.

But the problem is that If I don't use a Event like : `custom.eventBus();` (that is a http://square.github.io/otto/ ) I can't keep sync adapter with my service:
So I will have (for example after 10 seconds) a adapter data custom class with : 0 seconds and Service data with 10 seconds.

My methods it is working but I'm worried for a memory usage for fire every seconds a event.
Are there better ways for do this?

Comment: *I'm worried for a memory leak.* - why

Comment: for fire every second an event that refresh my data model adapter

Comment: do you know what a memory leak is?

Comment: sorry, lapsus, I'm worried for high memory usage.

Comment: but **why** - have you done any memory profiling or anything, something to back up your worries?

Comment: I'm doing a memory profiling, and now it work, even seems that with long usage of interface, I can see a little lag, but, In general, since I'm new in android programming, I would like hear opionion of someone more experienced. thanks :)